# Cannot access Strapi in a container using AWS Lightsail, Ubuntu, Docker and NGINX

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, docker-compose, strapi, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying to practice and I have created an instance using AWS Lightsail with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, also I've installed Docker and Docker Compose.

I would like to run this applications:

1. MariaDB
2. Strapi CMS

*Let's assume that my public IP is: 1.20.20.20*

When I try to access "http://1.20.20.20:1337", I receives "This site can’t be reached".

I thought that maybe I needed a web server and I have included NGINX in my docker-compose configuration.

**My folders in the instance:**

- envs/strapi.env
- nginx/strapi.conf
- docker-compose.yml

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
        nginx:
                image: nginx:stable
                container_name: nginx
                volumes:
                        - ./nginx/strapi.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
                ports:
                        - 80:80
                restart: on-failure
                depends_on:
                        - strapi

        db:
                image: mariadb:10.6.4
                container_name: db
                restart: always
                env_file:
                        - envs/db.env
                volumes:
                        - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
                networks:
                        - apps

        strapi:
                image: strapi/strapi:3.6.8
                container_name: strapi
                env_file:
                        - envs/strapi.env
                restart: always
                depends_on:
                        - db
                ports:
                        - 1337:1337
                networks:
                        - apps

volumes:
        db-data:

networks:
        apps:
                driver: bridge
```

**nginx/strapi.conf** (I have copied the configuration from [Strapi docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/optional-software/nginx-proxy.html#nginx-virtual-host)):

```
server {
    # Listen HTTP
    listen 1337;
    server_name 1.20.20.20;

    # Static Root
    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    # Strapi API
    location /api/ {
        rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://strapi;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }

    # Strapi Admin
    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://strapi/admin;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
}
```

Still cannot access the CMS using my browser.

For some reason, when I do "docker ps -a", the status of the nginx container is always Restarting....

I have tried to follow and read steps that I have found on a few articles without luck. I don't have a lot of experience using NGINX and Ubuntu servers.

My goal is to be able to access the web app (Strapi CMS) through my browser.

Any help would be appreciated.